# Debugging delays in the event-loop

Tags: node.js, debugging

We use Nodejs and are pretty happy with it. We monitor the performance of our Node.js processes by measuring how 'busy' is the event loop. Basically, we have a function like this

```
var previousTick;
setInterval(function() {
    now = Date.now();
    if(previousTick) {
        // check (now - statsPeriod - previousTick)
    }
    previousTick = now;
}, 1000);
```

Recently, as the load started to increase on some of our servers, we started to notice that sometimes, the delay was huge: up to 500 seconds on some of processes. This is a problem obviously.

We're really not sure what is going on here and we're looking for answer.
We tried using the [node debugger](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html), but, even though we can easily connect to the process when it runs normally using `node debug -p <pid>`, we cannot connect to it *during* the "delay".

Any idea what tool or technique we could use? Of course, we cannot rproduce consistently, eve though we see this happening a couple times a day on our production servers.

I want ahead and installed strace... and on a stuck process, here's what it yiels:

> clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1407798758, 934775226}) = 0
>   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1407798758, 934941698}) = 0
>   futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038,
>   FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
>   futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038,
>   FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
>   futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038,
>   FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
>   futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038,
>   FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
>   futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038,
>   FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
>   futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038,
>   FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
>   futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038,
>   FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1 futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
>   futex(0x20a1038, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1

Any idea what that might be?

[UPDATE]
Going a bit further let us find that our [process is stuck in a loop](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/419) with Timer.js.

Comment: One of the usual techniques for initially debugging sporadic events is to add a bunch of logging to the server so you can hopefully gather some info when a delay happens.  Usually, this is an iterative process where your first round of info points you in a direction, you add more logging in that direction, learn some more, add some more logging, etc... until finally you're able to figure out what is causing the delay. Sometimes, I've found I even have to write some tools to process the logs to analyze them and find the information I'm looking for.